# How to get id from php loop in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I'm trying to get the id for each row shown in while loop in my jquery function

Here are the request and view (PHP code)

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <div class="table responsive">
      <thead class="black white-text">
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Nom et Prénoms</th>
          <th>Fonction</th>
          <th>Université</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Contact</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php 

          $result = $connection->query($stmt) ;

          if($result->rowCount() > 0)
          {
            while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
            {

            echo '<tr>
                <td scope="row">'.$row["id"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["nom"].'</td>
                <td> '.$row["fonction"].'</td>
                <td> '.$row["nomU"].'</td>
                <td> '.$row["email"].'</td>
                <td> '.$row["Contact"].'</td>
                <td>' ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success valider">Valider</button> /<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rejeter">Rejeter</button>
<?php 
                  echo '</td>
                  <td>'
                ?>
<input type="hidden" class="the_id" value='<?php echo $row[' id ']; ?>'>

<?php echo '</td>
             </tr>';

            }
          }
          else
          {
            echo "0 results";
          }
        ?>

      </tbody>
    </div>
  </table>

</div>
```

And I want to show the id of each row when I click on the button "valider" for the line with jquery but it's showing the first id for all the row.

Here is th jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.valider').click(function(e){

      alert($('.the_id').val());
    });


  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost right. Remember that when accessing by a class name rather than an ID, you will get all of those objects.

So, we need to be more specific. Give this a try:

```
$('.valider').click(function(e){
   var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('td').find('.the_id').val();
   alert(id);
});
```

This takes you from `$(this)`, your button, to its parent `<td>`, then the parent `<tr>`, then looks for any classes of `.the_id` inside the tr, in other words, the specific one you want.

Comment: I get undefined like output

Answer (score 1):

You need to go up to the parent `tr` to get the related `input` so you could use `closest()` with the `$(this)` :

```
$('.valider').click(function(e){
   alert( $(this).closest('tr').find('.the_id').val() );
});
```

Comment: Side note: closest is more efficient than parent and parents

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a custom attribute to the elements, like `data-custom-id`.

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-success valider" data-custom-id="'.$row["id"].'">Valider</button>'
```

And then in the calling function I can access the object with `this`

```
$('.valider').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('data-custom-id'));
});
```

Comment: Great to hear @morten :) Please consider marking the answer that helped you the most, as solution for your question.